# Is it possible to update/refresh NodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a "Maindiv" (div) with, say, 4 elements in it. Lets consider the elements belong to a class called "Subdiv". When I query the number of "Subdivs" with  "Maindiv.getElementsByClassName('Subdiv').length;" , it returns 4, as expected. But if I create a new "Subdiv" and append it to my main "Maindiv" and instantly query for the length, it will return 4 (which is wrong), and until the NodeList is updated (usually 20-50 milliseconds after appending the new element) it returns 4. Finally after this interval it returns the right number (5). My question is, if there's a way to update/refresh the NodeList faster just after I append the new element?

```
<div>
  <div id='Maindiv'>
    <div class='Subdiv' id='Subdiv1'></div>
    <div class='Subdiv' id='Subdiv2'></div>
    <div class='Subdiv' id='Subdiv3'></div>
    <div class='Subdiv' id='Subdiv4'></div>
  </div>
<button type='button' onclick='CreateNewSubdivs()'>Create Subdiv</button>
</div>

    <script>
function CreateNewSubdivs(){
var MainDiv = document.getElementById('Maindiv');
var SubdivsLength= MainDiv.getElementsByClassName('Subdiv').length;
var NewSubDiv = document.createElement('div');
var NewCopyNumber = SubdivsLength+1;
var NewSubDivID = 'Subdiv'+NewCopyNumber;
NewSubDiv.setAttribute('class', 'Subdiv');
NewSubDiv.setAttribute('id', NewSubDivID );
MainDiv.appendChild(NewSubDiv );
var SubdivsLength= MainDiv .getElementsByClassName('Subdiv').length;
console.log(SubdivsLength);  /// This number is wrong until 20-50 millisec later
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NodeList` can either be a static or "live" collection of nodes.

> In some cases, the NodeList is live, which means that changes in the DOM automatically update the collection.

e.g. `Node.childNodes`

> In other cases, the NodeList is static, where any changes in the DOM does not affect the content of the collection.

e.g. a list returned by `querySelectorAll()`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

---

As you can see in this example, I set a reference to `childNodes` once. It is kept up to date as soon as the DOM changes.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#main');
const items = list.childNodes;

setInterval(() => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerHTML = '';
  list.appendChild(item);
  console.log(items.length);
}, 500);
```

```html
<ul id="main"></ul>
```

---

`getElementsByClassName` also returns a live collection of nodes:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#main');
const spans = list.getElementsByClassName('burrito');

setInterval(() => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerHTML = '<li><span class="burrito"></span></li>';
  list.appendChild(item);
  console.log(spans.length);
}, 1);
```

```html
<ul id="main">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm doing the same thing as you did, but it does not return the right length when you have many MainDivs and many SubDivs in them. I thought there's a way to refresh the list faster, but as you said, the list is refreshed automatically, and it seems, the problem is that it takes some time to refresh because of the number of elements I have.

Comment: The code sample you posted is *not* the same. Try using `childNodes`.

Comment: Thanks again, but that's not possible for me, I need to get them by ClassName, since there are other childNodes there. Unfortunately I can't upvote, I'm new here.

Comment: If the elements you need to count are direct children, you can still use `childNodes` and filter out the elements you don't want to include in your count.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. So if I get them by childNodes, then create an array and push those that have the ClassName I want into the array, it would work? I need to do other things with them too, it's not only the length I need.

Comment: By direct children you mean, not grandchildren? if that's the case, unfortunately they are grandchildren, and sometimes grand-grandchildren.

Comment: Updated my answer; `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection of nodes too.

Comment: You are right, it works for your example, but mine is different

Comment: The problem with your example is that at no point you hold a reference to a live collection.

Comment: Your example works, mine doesn't, I guess it's because they are not direct children as you said. I have no doubt that the code I'm using is not wrong. It's something similar to the one I wrote in my example but more complex. But I guess you gave me some ideas about the solution. I should test and see. My MainDiv contains about 2000 divs. First divided into some 2nd rank divs, then into some 3rd rank divs, then into some 4th rank divs, then into some 5th rank divs, and finally my Subdivs. It's very complex. I guess that's why it takes time until the NodeList is updated.